# How to remove a file without affecting other file upload in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to upload a file in the header and after clicking submit, the uploaded file will be assigned to other file uploads but when I click the (X) button, all of the file upload associated will be removed as well. The sample image is uploaded [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZlFw.png).

As much as possible, please limit the solution to JavaScript/jQuery only. Thanks.

Sample code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<p>Click on the "Choose File" button to upload a file:</p>


  <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename">
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" onclick="test(event)">
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="button" value="X" onclick="removeFile('#myFile1')"><input type="file" id="myFile1" name="filename">
  <input type="button" value="X" onclick="removeFile('#myFile2')"><input type="file" id="myFile2" name="filename">
  <input type="button" value="X" onclick="removeFile('#myFile3')"><input type="file" id="myFile3" name="filename">


<script>
function test(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#myFile1")[0].files = $("#myFile")[0].files;
    $("#myFile2")[0].files = $("#myFile")[0].files;
    $("#myFile3")[0].files = $("#myFile")[0].files;
}

function removeFile(value)
{
    $(value).val('');
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Do not be confused that when after removing a file, there is still file uploaded which is actually isn't.

Comment: the image is not enough you need to post your code as well, at least for others to inspect the problem,

Comment: code has been added

Comment: that is the javascript code you also need to add your html, Kindly make sure to post a useful Question to get a useful answer. try to read more on stack overflow for how to post your question https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: code updated, this is the best that I can do at least.

Answer (score 0):

your code correctly running! see this fiddle:
with no change:

```
function test(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#myFile1")[0].files = $("#myFile")[0].files;
    $("#myFile2")[0].files = $("#myFile")[0].files;
    $("#myFile3")[0].files = $("#myFile")[0].files;
}

function removeFile(value)
{
    $(value).val('');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4mks8r59/

Comment: Yes, it will still display the file but it has no value anymore. Try deleting and get the value of any of the file.